# How to get available/free sdcard space in android with adb command

Tags: android, adb, diskspace

I am trying to get free sdcard space with adb command, but I could not able to achieve. Any suggestions how to get the sdcard space.

Comment: How do you get the results in KB? My df command returns GB which is not granular enough

Comment: @JoshGraham use `df -h` for human readable.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Use **`df`**, as with any Linux distro. Not all Android devices may have it, but it usually seems to be available.

Comment: Thanks df command works!! I tried on Samsung SIII, Note, Nexus 5, SIV and it worked. To get the free space for sdcard, I used this command: adb shell df /data

Comment: If you don't have the df command in the shell try to run it from within [busybox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BusyBox): `adb shell busybox df -h | grep '^/dev/fuse'` . If you don't have busybox, install it :-)

Comment: I'm getting busybox, since df options (like `-h`) aren't working.

Answer (score 30):

1. **df**: Disk space details.

   adb shell df
2. **du**: Disk space used by the specified files and subdirectories.

   adb shell du
3. **df -h**: Disk space details in KB/MB format.

   adb shell df -h
4. **du -h**: Disk space used by the specified files and subdirectories in KB/MB format.

   adb shell du -h
5. For specific folder desk space details.

   adb shell df /system
6. For specific folder and sub-directories desk space details

   adb shell du /system
7. Only for the root level folders

   adb shell du -x -sh /*

Answer (score 2):

`df -h` to find disk usage and to find big files:

```
du -a <the_dir> | sort -n -r | head -n 20
```

Answer (score 0):

`du | sort -n -r` will mess up the hierarchy of folders, so I prefer `-t, --threshold=SIZE` to set a threshold.

But du on my Android phone doesn't have `-t, --threshold=SIZE` option

So I found an alternative:

```
du -m | awk '$1 >= 100'
```

(Display directories with a size >= 100MB)