# Not enough storage space on RPI3 running Android Things

Tags: android, raspberry-pi, adb, android-things

I'm working with multiple Raspberry Pi 3 Model B devices. They're running Android Things Developer Preview 0.6.1 (OIM1.171126.016).

After deploying a few times, the devices run out of storage space and prevent new deploys:

```
$ adb shell pm install -g -t -r "/data/local/tmp/my.package.name"
Error: android.os.ParcelableException: java.io.IOException: Requested internal only, but not enough space
Error while Installing APK
```

- The MicroSD cards have 16GB capacity
- The app ( < 10mb apk) has a database ( < 10mb total) and writes some log files ( < 100kb total).
- Uninstalling the app doesn't free up space.
- Invoking a factory reset (via the Android Things default launcher) doesn't seem to have any effect. Network settings and old logs are still there.
- This issue was also present in older Developer Preview builds.

Currently the only solution is to re-flash the build image, but doing that once or twice a day is a pain.

I'm looking for troubleshooting help and a way to free up storage space using the adb shell.

**Edit:**

Command results as suggested in comments:

```
rpi3:/ $ df
Filesystem            1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/root                499752  417004     72432  86% /
tmpfs                    380708     488    380220   1% /dev
tmpfs                    380708       0    380708   0% /mnt
/dev/block/mmcblk0p11     59308   10688     47332  19% /vendor
/dev/block/mmcblk0p19   2503464 2370588     90392  97% /data
/dev/block/mmcblk0p13    226396   64564    145476  31% /oem
/dev/fuse               2503464 2370588     90392  97% /storage/emulated
```

Comment: Check where the storage is being taken up. here are a list of possibly useful commands https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22947690/how-to-get-available-free-sdcard-space-in-android-with-adb-command

Comment: What is your oem partition size?

Comment: That's strange, I have an 8Gb sdcard and never had that problem. Check where the space is being used.

Comment: @tyczj I've updated the question. `/data` is almost full, but I don't know how to investigate further or how to fix this. When attempting to dig deeper into `/data`, I just get `Permission denied`

Comment: You need to be running as `root` to further explore the `/data` partition. You can reboot the ADB daemon into root mode with the `adb root` command (you may need to re-run `adb connect` afterwards). Then you can drill down and discover which data directory is taking all the space.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/41193879